# C pointer array not recognized in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, legacy, pointer-arithmetic

I'm converting/importing some legacy code into Swift and I have to use a file of constants that look like this:

Constants.h

```
extern const int workingConstant;
extern int constantArray1[];
extern int constantArray2[];
extern int constantArray3[];
extern int *problematicConstant[];
```

Constants.m

```
const int workingConstant = 3;
int constantArray1 [] = {2,50,50,49,47,46,44,42,16,41,49,47,46,44,42,41,16,64,64,62,62,60,60};
int constantArray2 [] = {72,718,63,740,94,756,117,755,127,759,121,767,120,777,118,788};
int constantArray3 [] = {226,505,226,505,213,518,206,531,230,545,250,562,258,575,265,560,277,543};
int* problematicConstant [] = {constantArray1,constantArray2,constantArray3}
```

In my legacy Objective C code I can import the header and call a method like:

```
-(void)doStuff:(int)firstConstant paths:(int **)paths shrink_p:(CGAffineTransform *)shrink_p{
   CGMutablePathRef hitPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    for(int i = 0; i < firstConstant; i++){
        CGPathMoveToPoint(hitPath, &(*shrink_p), paths[firstConstant][i+1]);
    } 
}
```

that takes the workingConstant and the problematicConstant and is a method of a subview. My .swift UIView subclass successfully finds the workingConstant however the problematicConstant is throwing a "Use of unresolved identifier" error when I try to call doStuff on my subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with some mock-up code.  For whatever reason Swift can't see `problematicConstant` via the bridging header.  However, I was able to circumvent this by adding yet another global variable:

```
extern int ** ppInt; // in the header

int ** ppInt = problematicConstant;  // in the Objective-C implementation
```

The `extern` declaration and definition can go into the existing Objective-C source or, if you want to keep it clean, into separate header and implementation files.  In fact, the `extern` can just be in the bridging header.

As an aside, the `constantArray...` declarations could not be bridged, either, but if you need them, you can do a similar trick:

```
int * pInt1 = constantArray1;
...
```